# PHP Mail Function is not working

Tags: php, mysql, email

I am having trouble sending email with the php mail function. I can't figure out what the cause might be. The script gives no errors even with strict error reporting. I am using 000webhost to test the system.

Strange thing is I've written much more complicated email systems in the past that have not given me any problems. I'm hoping somebody here can point me in the right direction. Thanks! :)

```
$look ="SELECT * FROM `contact` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query ($look);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo $row['first_name'] . "<br/>";
echo $row['email'] . "<br/>";
echo $row['message'] . "<br/>";

$to= 'xxx@xxx.com';
$subject= "Mail from your portfolio website";
$txt=$row['message'] . '<br/><br/>' . $row['email'] . '<br/>' . $row['first_name'] .      $row['last_name'];
$headers = "Reply-To: xxxx@myproject.com" . "r\n";

mail ($to, $subject, $txt, $headers);
}
```

Comment: stap 1, what does the mail log say

Comment: you dont have to go through the while loop. Your are fetching one row only.

Comment: @Basant
I see you what you mean. Thanks for the tip. :) ...I'm still having trouble getting my email to send, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the following questions but are needed to avoid some headaches:

1. Does you're query work? You may test this in your database.
2. Are you connected to your DB?
3. Does your server support mailing?

Then, if all these question have positive answers, you could add at the end of your code this two rows:

```
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $txt, $headers );
echo $mail_sent ? "sent mail" : "Impossible to send mail";
```

Let me know the results of this test.

EDIT
as said basant rijal, the while it's useless.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply!! Yes, the query works and there are no errors. -- I did what you asked and it said: "Sent mail."

Comment: Are you sure that your server support mailing? Are you hosting on which website?

Comment: Yes, the site says it supports mailing. I am using 000webhost. It's a free hosting service. I'm really confused here. ...I need the system to work for a project I'm doing in school.

Comment: It could be a stupid question but... did you check the spam mails?

Comment: Yep, nothing in the spam mail. Second place I looked.